# java:Tomcat 9 status code 200 but response message null

Tags: java, rest, http, tomcat

I have an http client that sends request to a RESTful web service and receives a response. It was working successfully when deployed in Tomcat 8. But when I tried to deploy the same client and server in Tomcat versions 8.5 and above, the server receives response code as 200 but response message is null instead of OK.

Below is my client code snippet

```
        httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        postrequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postrequest);
        
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("Response from server ");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
```

and my server code snippet for response is

```
@POST
@Path("/download/{filename}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile(@PathParam("filename") String file)
{
    try
    {               
        File downloadfile = new File("/home/upload/"+file);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) downloadfile);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", downloadfile.getName());
        
        return response.build();
            
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Error is : "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
}
```

The output I get is just

> Response from server
>
> 200

It should actually be

> Response from server
>
> 200
>
> OK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the reported issue in tomcat, they have stopped sending "Reason Phrase" from tomcat 8.5 version onward.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60183